# Zendesk: Admin users can't use Enterprise SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, zendesk, zendesk-app

I have enabled Enterprise SSO on zendesk so that users in my external Identity server can login to Zendesk. Setup is successfully made and users in my system can do SSO with Zendesk.

But As a admin I can't do SSO with zendesk from my external application, other end users and agents can do. What could be the root cause of this?

Comment: what exactly happens that you `can't do SSO with Zendesk`?  Step by step how do you manage the flow, what behaviour do you see, What have you tried to resolve the issue?  Do you have any logs?

Comment: How to see logs in Zendesk? I got logout and redirected to login page without any error message.

Comment: The logs I mean in this case would be from the Identity Server.  Also you can use your browser developer tools to track the network requests.  These requests can be very informative about the issue.